# spaCy: fix/override part of speech of a token

Tags: nlp, spacy

If some token part of speech is recognized incorrectly by spaCy, can I set the correct PoS for the token, before the document is parsed, to receive correct dependencies for the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's impossible, at least I haven’t found a way to do it. The spaCy documentation [says](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines):

> In spaCy v2.x, the statistical components like the tagger or parser are independent and don’t share any data between themselves. For example, the named entity recognizer doesn’t use any features set by the tagger and parser, and so on. This means that you can swap them, or remove single components from the pipeline without affecting the others.